# Add comments to div using pure js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could I add comments to some div element, using just js (or js/jquery)?

For example:

I have a form:

```
<form action="#" id="create" method="post">
    <fieldset>

    <legend><strong>Add your comment</strong></legend>

    <p>
        <label for="author">Name <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
        <input name="author" id="author" value=""
        required="required" aria-required="true"
        pattern="^([- wdu00c0-u024f]+)$"
        title="Your name"
        type="text" spellcheck="false" size="20" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="email">Email <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
        <input name="email" id="email" value=""
        required="required" aria-required="true"
        pattern="^(([-wd]+)(.[-wd]+)*@([-wd]+)(.[-wd]+)*(.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}|[d]{1,3})){1,2})$"
        title="Your email address"
        type="text" spellcheck="false" size="30" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="text">Comment <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
        <textarea name="text" id="text"
        required="required" aria-required="true"
        title="Your comment"
        spellcheck="true" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>

    <button name="preview" type="submit">Preview</button>
    <button name="save" type="submit">Submit Comment</button>

    </fieldset>

</form>

<div id="comments"></div>
```

Afterwards I'm trying to submit this form and after submission add textarea content to the div element which is placed next to the form. Obviously, I can't do it without the page reloading.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: You can use pure Angular for best performance.

Answer (score 4):

Using pure JS :

```
document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = 'Form sent!';
```

Using jQuery :

```
$('#comments').html('Form sent!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following javascript function to page code

```
<script>
 function updateComment()
  {  
   document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
  }
</script>
```

And call this function on "Onclick" event of "Submit Comments" button

```
<button name="save" type="submit" onclick="updateComment()">Submit Comment</button>
```